# When I try to run the npm in the terminal, it showing the error

Tags: reactjs, compiler-errors

When I try to run the `npm` in the terminal, it is showing an error like below:

**Error:**

```
Failed to compile.
./src/App.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './App.css' in 'Y:\Web Practicing tasks\React works\tourism\src'
```

Tried possible solutions but nothing worked, kindly help me on this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRCJR.png)

Comment: Can you include a picture of your project folders/files? Maybe React cannot find you App.css because it is not in the src folder

Comment: Please attach your App.js file code.

Comment: This is my app.js file code - https://codepen.io/KMYasin/pen/oNWOpoq

This is my project folder - https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRCJR.png

Comment: Restart your server and kill the port operation and you will good to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing package-lock.json, run npm install and then npm start again. Please also share your package.json file.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more details please ?

However it its likely caused by "App.css" has been deleted of the project but you still have the following line in your App.js

```js
import "./App.css";
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I've already removed it.
And I didn't import it anywhere in the project.

Comment: Do you have this line anywhere else ?

Comment: No, never used it anywhere

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are missing App.css.
What steps have you tried already?
Is there an App.css file within you src folder?
I would create a file named App.css inside this exact path `Y:\Web Practicing tasks\React works\tourism\src` or you can remove the import statement inside the App.js file.

Without seeing the project folder, that's all I can tell.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reponse, But I don't have any app.css file in the SRC folder, already I've removed it. Even I checked the same in the folder but it's doesn't work.

Comment: Please see the folder image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRCJR.png

Comment: I've attached the images and code here, kindly look into it and suggest me the solution.

Comment: I would do a few things: 1) make sure you kill the app and try running the app again. 2) Search all you files and see if App.css is imported anywhere.
3) just create a blank App.css in src.

Comment: Even I tried close all the file and create a new project but if i remove the App.css file it showing the same error.
In the current version, is that mandatory to keep those files in the projects?

Comment: Even If I added the App.css file, then it's asking logo.svg which means it's asking all removed files in the project.